# `Char' is applied to too many type arguments

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a haskell program that takes in a string and returns a new string that only contains the vowels but I'm getting this error.

```
`Char' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `vowels': vowels :: Char a => a -> a
```

Here's my code:

```
vowels :: (Char a) => a -> a
vowels str = [ x | x <- str, x `elem` ['A','E','I','U','Y','O']]
```

Comment: Can you tell what the type of your function should be?

Comment: List of chars :/ For that reason I have previously tried to use 
vowels :: (Char [a]) => [a] -> [a] 
but i was getting the same error :/

Comment: So you have a function that *takes* a list of `Char` and *returns* a list of `Char`. You write that as `[Char] -> [Char]` (i.e., you replace the generic `a` with `Char`). `(Char a) => ...` would say that `a` is an instance of the `Char` type class (if it existed), which is a very different thing.

Comment: Just for the record: as far as I knew, at the time I clicked "close", I was casting the first vote out of five to close it. Though I believe this is in fact a duplicate (so I don't intend to vote to re-open this, and don't necessarily encourage others to do so either), it was not my intention to unilaterally close this, and I'm not sure how it happened.

Comment: @DanielWagner I guess it has to do with this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/242059

Comment: To be honest I saw the answer to that questions that's supposed to be a duplicate of my question and the answers there didn't really answer my question so that's why I created a new question :S

Comment: @user3334838 As far as I'm concerned, the question as it stands is a duplicate: it is little more than "GHC gave me such-and-such an error, why?", and the other question has the same form. However, with a bit of work on your part, it could be _made_ into a different question; for example, by explaining what you understood from the other question's answer, and why you don't believe it answers your question. This will also allow the answers here to be targeted more towards your actual problem, and both you and future users will get better value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your type signature should be

```
vowels :: [Char] -> [Char]
vowels str = [ x | x <- str, x `elem` ['A','E','I','U','Y','O']]
```

or

```
vowels :: String -> String
```

In your code, `(Char a) => ...` indicates that the type `a` should be an instance of the typeclass `Char`. However, `Char` is a data type, not a type class which is why you get the error. Since you don't need any classes to implement this function you can just remove the constraint.

Comment: that works thanks. I tried to change my type signature to 
`vowels :: (Char [a]) -> [a] -> [a]` just by curiosity after following your example above but that's throwing the same error.. is there a specific reason why this is wrong?

Comment: @user3334838 You seem to be confusing types with typeclasses. When you see something like `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, that is *not* the same thing as `Eq -> Eq -> Bool` – the latter is an error and not valid Haskell code. When you see `Eq a`, you should be reading, "Any type `a` that is a member of the `Eq` typeclass." `Char` is *not* a typeclass, so it can't have members!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
vowels :: String -> [Char]
vowels = let
             y =  ['A','a','E','e','I','i','U','u','Y','y','O',o']
         in filter.(\x -> elem x y)
```

Comment: Yes but I was trying to use a simpler version for the time being as I have just started learning Haskell and im not really used to using the "lambda" notation etc